# Perl Parsing Without Package

Tags: perl

I have a csv file containing data that I would like to parse and store into some data structure to print onto the screen. I don't have options to install any packages or modules that aren't pre-installed. I am familiar with CSV text mod but cannot use it so I have to do this manually.

The data looks like this:

```
Name,Age,Weight,Target  
April,     23,    134,    90  
Jenna,     45,    156,    90  
Matt,      12,    90,     90  
Aaron,     34,    190,    90  
Daniel,    22,    188,    90
```

Here is what I have so far, but it simply stores all the data into an array and prints it out.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = "file.csv";

my %people;
my @data;

open my $fh, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split(/,/, $line);
    push @data, @fields;
}
close $fh;

print join(", ", @data);
```

This gives an output like:

```
Name, Age, Weight, Target, April        ,          23,       134,     90,
```

The spacing is due to the csv columns being spaced out. The header line has no spaces. I would like a more organized way of storing each columns values and then printing them out on the screen.

Comment: You can install Text::CSV to a [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib), bundle it with your application using [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton), or pack Text::CSV_PP into your script using [App::FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker).

Comment: @Grinnz my work is very strict about using anything that is not pre-installed. so it will not work on my current system.

Comment: Then I hope you are aware of just how many complications can arise in parsing CSVs that is handled by this module. https://donatstudios.com/Falsehoods-Programmers-Believe-About-CSVs

Comment: Your immediate problems can be solved by using an [array of arrays](https://perldoc.pl/perllol) and using the split pattern `/\s*,\s*/` which will remove any non-significant spaces surrounding the commas. Things get much more complicated if you have any quoted fields, such as fields containing commas, spaces, or quotes.

Comment: Re "*my work is very strict about using anything that is not pre-installed.*", So how do you get the script on the machine? Why is our untested code on SO better than our tested code on CPAN?

Comment: @ikegami i mean using packages that are not pre-installed. most of the time, the easiest way to go about something is using an already existing perl package like in this case Text::CSV but I simply do not have permissions to use it. There's absolutely nothing I can do about that.

Comment: There is no difference between a script and a module, so what you're saying it's true. Either you can install Perl code, or you can't.

Comment: sfr -- what @ikegami means is that you _can_ "install" a module, as a user. Much like the code you write.  Often you can even merely copy it where you want it, along with modules you wrote for your project.  There may be some dependencies but you can add those.  Not to mention that you _can_ properly install modules as a user,  at a location of your choosing.  (Is that a no-no as well?) Most of CPAN modules are straight files with Perl code.

Comment: If you're going to re-invent the wheel, why not take a look at the wheel first?  
https://metacpan.org/source/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-2.00/lib/Text/CSV_PP.pm (and then copy and paste the wheel into your work directory and treat it like the script you're trying to write.

Comment: @zdim i understand that but I've previously tried to do so in Python, and as you mentioned there are almost always dependencies that cause issues. In the end, it almost always turned out easier to write a longer code with no modules, than to copy paste a bunch of code that is most likely depending on more code which may take a long amount of time to get sorted out.

Comment: OK, yes, funny dependencies _can_ ruin it. So you've seen the game. I think that in Perl it mostly isn't that bad, except for some large libraries.  (See `CSV_PP` from @TrentonTrama comment -- no dependencies at all! Nearly 3k lines though.)  The best way may be to pick up a good library and work through its code, to get a version suitable for your needs. It'll be some work but if you need complex capabilities it won't be quick in any way.  Or -- better -- see whether they're OK with user-installed libs, in user space.

Comment: @zdim you're right but good news. I found that I've been able to use Text::CSV if I use a different version of Perl than the one I am currently on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my work is very strict about using anything that is not pre-installed.

Ah well.  There's a lot that can be said about that, some of it mentioned in comments. But I'd leave it at this point since the question is quite clear and articulate on that.

If your data is always like shown then things are easy. But I suggest to also add code that checks for gremlins in your data, things that would throw off manual parsing; a pre-processing check of sorts. So that you get warned when that happens.

Having said that, and with a nice use of formats in another answer, I'd like to comment on the code.

The problem is that the line

```
push @data, @fields;
```

evaluates `@fields` into a list of its elements and then adds those elements to the array -- it does not somehow "add the array" `@fields` as a single entity, which I presume is what you expected. So as it keeps going through lines it keeps building that loooong array, with all data in one long flat list.

Instead, add a reference to the `@fields` array

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
    push @data, \@fields;
}
```

where I've also pruned spaces, once we're at it.  (The CSV shouldn't have them at all, actually.)

Here we can nicely just take a reference of `@fields` becuase it's declared anew for each iteration.  If it were declared elsewhere and merely overwritten in each iteration then you'd have to have it copied (into an anonymous array) instead

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    @fields = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;   # if @fields is declared outside
    push @data,  [ @fields ];
}
```

or you'd end up with the same reference for all elements of `@data`.

Now elements of `@data` are references to rows and can be processed individually. For example

```
use List::Util qw(max);  

my $max_name_wt = max map { length $_->[0] } @data;

printf "%${max_name_wt}s %6s %6s %6s\n", @{ shift @data };  # headers

foreach my $row (@data) {
    printf "%${max_name_wt}s %6d %6d %6d\n", @$row;
}
```

This assumes that numbers are all integer with at most 6 digits. It also assumes that no fields are missing, or their `undef` would draw warnings in `printf`. The [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) is a core module.

There are simpler ways to print complex data structures; see core [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).

Answer (score 1):

If cool printing on screen is all you need and fields in your files are the same, try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(CSV, "< file.csv") or die "Can't open input file!\n";
my ($name, $age, $weight, $target);
format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<
$name,    $age,     $weight,  $target
.
while ( my $line = <CSV> ) {
    chomp($line);
    ($name, $age, $weight, $target) = split(/,\s*/, $line);
    write;
}
close(CSV);
```

output:

```
$ ./parse_csv.pl 
Name      Age       Weight    Target
April     23        134       90
Jenna     45        156       90
Matt      12        90        90
Aaron     34        190       90
Daniel    22        188       90
```

Answer (score 0):

OP does not posses full understanding of complex data structure.

Please see the code below which fills a hash with data. The data can be manipulated any imaginable way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;                          # debug flag

my %people;                             # store people's data

while(<DATA>){
    next if /^\s*$/;                    # skip empty lines
    next if /Name\,Age/;                # skip header
    s/\s+//g;                           # remove spaces
    my @data = split ',';               # obtain data
    my %param;                          # temp hash 
    @param{qw/age weight target/} = @data[1..3];
    $people{$data[0]} = \%param;        # store param hash reference
}

say Dumper(\%people) if $debug;

$~ = 'STDOUT_HEADER';
write;
$~ = 'STDOUT';

my($person,$data);

while( ($person,$data) = each %people ) {
    write;
}

$~ = 'STDOUT_FOOTER';
write;

format STDOUT_HEADER =
+--------------+-----+--------+--------+
| Name         | Age | Weight | Target |
+--------------+-----+--------+--------+
.

format STDOUT =
| @<<<<<<<<<<< | @>> |   @>>> |    @>> |
$person, $data->{age}, $data->{weight}, $data->{target}
.

format STDOUT_FOOTER =
+--------------+-----+--------+--------+
.

__DATA__
Name,Age,Weight,Target  
April,     23,    134,    90  
Jenna,     45,    156,    90  
Matt,      12,    90,     90  
Aaron,     34,    190,    90  
Daniel,    22,    188,    90
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Daniel' => {
                        'weight' => '188',
                        'age' => '22',
                        'target' => '90'
                      },
          'April' => {
                       'target' => '90',
                       'age' => '23',
                       'weight' => '134'
                     },
          'Aaron' => {
                       'target' => '90',
                       'age' => '34',
                       'weight' => '190'
                     },
          'Matt' => {
                      'weight' => '90',
                      'age' => '12',
                      'target' => '90'
                    },
          'Jenna' => {
                       'target' => '90',
                       'age' => '45',
                       'weight' => '156'
                     }
        };


+--------------+-----+--------+--------+
| Name         | Age | Weight | Target |
+--------------+-----+--------+--------+
| Aaron        |  34 |    190 |     90 |
| Jenna        |  45 |    156 |     90 |
| Daniel       |  22 |    188 |     90 |
| Matt         |  12 |     90 |     90 |
| April        |  23 |    134 |     90 |
+--------------+-----+--------+--------+
```